# Why does the start pointer change during the load from file?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am coding in "C" language,using "CodeBlocks Editor",with the Compiler "GNU GCC".
I'm trying to make links list from this structure:

```
struct node
{
char *name;
struct node *next;
} node;
```

which contains a string name and a pointer of type node(for saving the next item's address)

I wrote the below code:

```
    void load(FILE *p);
    void add(node *add);
      typedef struct node 
      {
      char *name;
      struct node *next;
      } node;

    node *start=NULL;
    int main()
    {
    FILE *p;
    *p=fopen("FILENAME","r+");
        if(p==NULL)
        {
        printf("Can not open the file");
        getch();
        return 0;
        }
    load(p);
    return 0;
    }

    void add(node *add)
    {
     node *c=start;
      if(start==NULL)
      {
      start=add;
      start->next=NULL;
      }
       else
       {
         while((c->next)!=NULL)
         {
         c=c->next;
         }
      c->next=add;
     add->next=NULL;
     }

    }

    void load(FILE *p)
    {
    char line[30],*name;

        while(!feof(p))
        {
        fscanf(p,"%s",line);
         node *e=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
         e->name=line;
//comment line1:next line adds e to link list
         add(e);
    printf("%s,%s\n",e->name,start->name);

        }

    }
```

in which the file pointed by the `FILE *p` is a notepad text file containing the following value:

```
#
Alex
Ali
```

By running the code,i expected to view something like this:

```
#,#
Alex,#
Ali,#
```

But actually it was something else:

```
##
AlexAlex
AliAli
```

which means the `start` global pointer is **changing with the change of pointer e(of type node)**.We know that every running of function `malloc` allocates a **new space in the Heap**.so it is reasonable that the successive values that `e` takes in the `load` function are different.so different nodes are added to links list according to the next line after comment line1.But the unusual thing is that the pointer `start`  is changing just like the pointer `e` does.
I've allowed  start to change **just when it's NULL at the beginning** but it still continues changing(look at the definition of add function).
What's happening?

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but `while(!feof(p))` is the wrong way to check for end of file in C.

Comment: Also,the value for `start` changes precisely once during the program's execution, using the data you've supplied. Why dont you use the debugger in Code::Blocks yourself and have a closer look?

Comment: The code that you have shown doesn't compile. There are several errors, for example that the function `add` has been written twice. Therefore, what you have posted here _does not seem to be the program that you are running._ That can make it a bit difficult for us to help you find your error, don't you think?

Comment: @Thomas Padron-McCarthy:Yes.You are right.I made changes to my code.the add function declaration was copied twice but it seems the questioned was understood.The answer worked very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, line as below is most probably wrong:

```
 e->name=line;
```

because `line` is a local variable in the function, so in general when function goes out of scope, where will `e->name` point to? (use `strcpy` instead to copy contents of `line` to `e->name` - but before that, don't forget to allocate memory for `e->name` using `malloc` or use `strdup`).

But particularly in your case problem seems to be that *each* `e->name` points to the *same* memory location: `line`. (and it seems you are confused by thinking that = operator copies the string, no it doesn't, it just makes `e->name` point to `line`). Solution is similar as suggested in above paragraph.

Also don't forget to `free` memories which you have allocated.

Comment: e points to fixed location in Heap that doesn't change when going out of scope.the value of line is not important.The main thing is that while the load function is running we shoud copy the value of line string to the e->name which is also a string.what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Agent47: So how are you copying value of line to e->name?

Comment: `"use strcpy instead to copy contents of line to e->name"` Nooooooooo! `e->name is a pointer` - it does not point to memory that has had space allocated to store the string. You should be using `e->name = strdup(line);`, which will make a copy of the string (including allocating memory for it) before setting the e->name pointer to point to this new copy of the string.

Comment: @Agent47: That line does not copy the string.

Comment: @enhzflep: yeah sure, forgot that; assumed it was allocated for some reasons.